# How to launch android wear service app?

Tags: android, android-service, wear-os, android-wear-notification

As you know, after the wear app installed through mobile app, a notification appears on watch screen that shows:

> App Installed. Touch to Start.

but if the app be a service application, it didn't start by touching the notification. so how can start it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Wear: Starting a service on Handheld](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656252/android-wear-starting-a-service-on-handheld)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I don't think. The OP wants to start a service on the **watch**, not the handheld.

Comment: Question for Siyamak: how would you normally expect your service to be started?